# Configuring Apache2 httpd.conf to allow uploading files; using python client with pycurl to upload

Tags: python, upload, apache2, httpd.conf, pycurl

I need to configure the Apache 2.2 web server to allow uploading files to a particular directory, say `/tmp/www/upload/` on the server. I want to perform the upload with a python client, and tried the pycurl example in `/usr/share/doc/python-pycurl/examples/file_upload.py`, which is part of the python 2.6.5 distribution on my ubuntu 10.04 machine, with the localhost web server, on which the `http://127.0.1.1/upload/` URL is mapped to the dir `/tmp/www/upload/`.

Probably I need to enable a handler in the Apache `httpd.conf` file to allow uploading files, "going through" a script on the server, but I can't figure out how to get started.

Answer (score 2):

The example you're referring to only shows how you can upload a file to a server, that means how you can *send* the file.

You still need to write the server side code which receives and writes the file to the disk. A very basic example of how this could be done is [here](http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_file_upload).